# Top 10 and items upon user's demand

Tags: tableau-api

fellow Tableau Developer,

Take the super store database for example, it is easy to draw a histogram displaying the sales amount of each customer and to only display the Top 10 customers.

It is also easy to build a multiple dropdown filter to let the user to specify some customers at the user's will.

But, is it possible to combine the two of them, namely, to display Top 10 customers and in the same graph display a few other customers (possibly not in the Top 10) on the user's demand?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straight forward solution that works with Tableau Desktop, but not as useful currently on Tableau Server. The viz still works on Server, but you can can't alter the list of specific users on Server.

Here's the approach.

1. Create a set to represent your Top 10 customers -- a *computed* set. (right click on the [Customer Name] field, and Create Set)
   [image]
2. Create a second set to represent your specific list of customers of interest -- a *static* set (select [Customer Name] and Create Set)
   [image]
3. Create a combined set to be the union of both sets and place it on the filter shelf. (select both sets, right click and create a combined set)
   [image]
4. Use your combined set on the filter shelf, row shelf, in calculations, as desired.

A desktop user can edit the Interesting Customers set. Sure wish there was a control similar to "show filter" for editing set members.

If you'd like this feature more flexible in Desktop, and even available on Tableau Server, upvote the following idea 
https://community.tableau.com/ideas/5193